# Laravel has_many relationships issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

i have next issue:
I have two tables:

1. pages

| id | title | content | description | image | status | noindex | viewed | author | template_id | created_at | updated_at |

2. page_relations

| id | page_id | parent_id |

And my task is: i want to output pages by relationship.
For example: page 1 is parent of a page 2.

What i did:
in my model i use has_many:

```
  public function relation(){
    return $this->hasMany(PageRelation::class , 'parent_id');
  }
```

in my controller i add:

```
$pages = Pages::with('relation')->get();
```

But in dd() i saw that i get all pages with bound relations to that by value in page_relations table.

[image]

But... My question: what should i do to get pages by this ids in this model.
For example: i have list of pages and have relations with child pages (not only ids from page_relations) with title, desctiption ... from pages table?

Comment: Please, whenever possible post plain text instead of immages! [Here is why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15432738)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `HasManyThrough` relation. In your case, `Page` has many `Page` through `PageRelation`. I think the docs will provide you with your answer - [link](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through).

On another note, there are other ways of handling that type of relation using a `parent_id` field on itself.

```php
// pages migration

// schema function
$table->id();
$table->string('page_name')
$table->unsignedInteger('parent_id')->nullable();
$table->timestamps();
// end schema function
```

```php
// Page.php
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Page::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}
```

I normally use this when the dataset will not be huge, instead of having an intermediary table. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer but i saw method with HasManyThrough and i can't understand something: if i have two models with two tables in my case its: pages and page_relations so what i should pass in arguments of function??
hasManyThrough(Deployment::class, Environment::class);

If i work with my Page model and i want bound this Page model with my PageRelation model i can apply only one argument, and this argument is PageRelation class... so what is second argument must be in that function?

Comment: You'd pass the models, `hasManyThrough(Pages::class, PageRelation::class)`, first is the model which is the child and the second is the table through which you can get the child.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have done it, i were fight it and won! :-)
.. and you save me!

Answer (score 0):

I had solve it by that:

```
public function relation(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
      Pages::class,
      PageRelation::class,
      'parent_id', // Foreign key on the PageRelation table...
      'id', // Foreign key on the Pages table...
      'id', // Local key on the projects table...
      'page_id' // Local key on the environments table...
    );
  }
```